# how to find respected project related for global library

Tags: package, nuget-package

How to find the reference or root of the project related to library-> location C:\Users\user1.nuget\packages.. from where it is installed or consumed?

Searched on all solutions by manage package solutions, that nuget is not showing as installed though it is there in global-packages locations.